# Math mode error in Shortunderstack

Tags: tables, errors, arrays, adjustbox

I'm getting some red dot errors like this from Overleaf while it still compliles good without any problem. After narrowing down the problem, I see that it's because of using the math mode inside `Shortunderstack`. 
How can I solve this problem?
Here are the errors:

> ```
> unclosed \begin{adjustbox} found at \end{array}
> unclosed \begin{adjustbox} found at \end{table}
> unexpected \end{array} after $
> unexpected \end{array} after \begin{adjustbox}
> unclosed $ found at \end{table}
> unclosed open group { found at $
> unexpected $ after open group {
> unexpected $ after \begin{array}
> unclosed $ found at \end{array}
> ```

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs,capt-of}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}


\begin{document}

 \begin{table}[!t]
      \centering
      \caption{A table}
      \label{tab:table 1}
    \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\linewidth}
    $\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
    \begin{array}{cc@{}cccccccl @{\quad}l }
    \toprule
    \textbf{No} & \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{List}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Note}} \\
    \midrule
    1 & ( & x_1, & x_2, & x_3, & x_1, & x_5, & x_6, & x_7 & ) & \Shortunderstack[l]{This is an example \\ of two line text}\\
    \addlinespace
    2 & ( & y_1, & y_2, & y_3, & y_4, & y_5, & y_6, & y_7 & ) & \Shortunderstack[l]{Math expression error $x_1+x_2$ } \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{array}$
    \end{adjustbox}
    \end{table}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get no error from your code.

Comment: @egreg not compilation error but if you put it on Overleaf you would get them marked in red with some red circles as in the image above.

Comment: Those are not errors. Apparently Overleaf doesn't know about valid LaTeX constructs. On the other hand, `\Shortunderstack` is not needed at all.

Comment: @egreg I see, I just removed `\Shortunderstack` and the errors gone.

Comment: It seems Overleaf's syntax parser gets confused by a math mode nested inside another math mode. It isn't aware of `\Shortunderstack` switching to text mode. What you can do, is wrap the inner math expression in `\text`: `\text{$x_1+x_2$}`

Comment: @PietervanOostrum I see, this is nice too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing you can do about that except informing the staff at Overleaf.

On the other hand, `adjustbox` and `\Shortunderstack` are not needed.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{table}[t]
\centering

\caption{A table}
\label{tab:table 1}

% local command
\newcommand{\stack}[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

$\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}cccccccl @{\enspace}l@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{No} & \multicolumn{9}{c}{\textbf{List}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Note}} \\
\midrule
1 & ( & x_1, & x_2, & x_3, & x_1, & x_5, & x_6, & x_7 & ) & 
  \stack{This is an example \\ of two line text}\\
\addlinespace
2 & ( & y_1, & y_2, & y_3, & y_4, & y_5, & y_6, & y_7 & ) &
  \stack{Math expression error \\ $x_1+x_2$ } \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}$

\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]